Asyncio only process 15 requests at a time
I want to send 100 requests at the same time with the code below. The test endpoint also mine, simply sleep for 5 seconds and return 200
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import datetime
async def send_request(session, id):
    url = f"https://example.com/test_api/{id}"
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            print(f"Finished for id {id} at {datetime.datetime.now()}")
        else:
            print(f"Request for ID {id} failed")

async def main():
    ids = range(1, 30)  # IDs from 1 to 10
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for id in ids:
            print(f"Start for id {id} at {datetime.datetime.now()}")
            task = asyncio.create_task(send_request(session, id))
            tasks.append(task)
            
        # Run all tasks concurrently
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())

This is the output when I run the code:
Start for id 1 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308105
Start for id 2 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308264
Start for id 3 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308328
Start for id 4 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308348
Start for id 5 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308374
Start for id 6 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308391
Start for id 7 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308408
......
Start for id 29 at 2024-05-13 19:48:15.308785
Finished for id 6 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.724524
Finished for id 18 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.724774
Finished for id 10 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.724965
Finished for id 1 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.725075
Finished for id 13 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.726419
Finished for id 12 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.727840
Finished for id 11 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.730933
Finished for id 20 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.738738
Finished for id 2 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.743643
Finished for id 5 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.744166
Finished for id 7 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.750183
Finished for id 4 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.751124
Finished for id 15 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.754580
Finished for id 16 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.775227
Finished for id 17 at 2024-05-13 19:48:20.775539

Finished for id 3 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.771361
Finished for id 29 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.771579
Finished for id 9 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.771706
Finished for id 8 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.773044
Finished for id 21 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.776847
Finished for id 28 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.776985
Finished for id 23 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777161
Finished for id 26 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777282
Finished for id 19 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777384
Finished for id 22 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777481
Finished for id 25 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777568
Finished for id 14 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777672
Finished for id 24 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777770
Finished for id 27 at 2024-05-13 19:48:25.777901

You see that the first 15 are sent together and the rest are sent after the first half finished. I also try 50, 100 requests and also the same issue, only 15 requests at a time. I also try on a different machine with different hardware.
Can you point out what is the problem and if there are other solutions to send 100, 1000 requests together in 1 shot, please suggest me.
I also try 50, 100 requests and also the same issue, only 15 requests at a time. I also try on a different machine with different hardware.
Can you point out what is the problem and if there are other solutions to send 100, 1000 requests together in 1 shot, please suggest me.

Are you sure the limit is coming from your asyncio outbound tasks and not from your testing endpoint only handling 15 incoming requests at a time?

@nigh_anxiety you are right, it was my endpoint problem.
